# How to prevent Windows from shutting down if a scheduled task is running?

Tags: windows, shutdown, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a task scheduled through Task Scheduler that can take a while to complete. I would like it to prevent Windows from shutting down (triggering the typical "waiting for program to close" message) if I tell Windows to shut down while it is running.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: The easiest way is to schedule the task for a time when Windows will not shut down automatically.

Comment: @John I was referring to when I manually shut down the computer. Taking into account that I don't know the exact moment when the task begins, and that it can take more or less for it to finish, I would need to manually check that the task is not running before shutting down the computer, which is far from ideal. It can take from seconds to more than an hour (it's a task for backing things up).

Comment: If you can reasonably estimate the task, you can use the shutdown command and give it a generous time allowance to shut down. That might work. You can also leave it on overnight and turn the monitor off.

Comment: @John I see two issues there. The first one is that I cannot estimate the time it will take to complete, since it depends on the size of the files to backup, the speed of my Internet connection... Also, it's a laptop, so leaving it on overnight. That's why I was specifically looking for a way to block the shut down of the machine once it starts.

Comment: Then consider leaving the computer on and turn the monitor off

Comment: The other thing you may be able to do is add a script to the conclusion of the task which issues the shutdown.

Comment: @John Sorry, I accidentally submitted the comment before it was finished. It's a laptop, so leaving it running overnight is not ideal. Even if it wasn't, leaving it on for the whole night day after day for a task that may be completed in a matter of minutes doesn't sound great.

Comment: @John the shutdown script option  doesn't suit me either. I may be using the laptop when the task finishes.

Comment: Too many issues, so just shut down the laptop when the task is done and you are done.

Comment: @John I don't think there are that many issues. It's a backup (critical) task running automatically in the background in a laptop. And I would like it to be completed no matter what I do (that's why I say it's critical). It's not such a corner case. Anyway, I don't see how doing exactly what I say I would like to a avoid in OP can be an acceptable solution for my needs.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question because ALL the ideas posted are not suitable to you. Too muddy from my point of view,

Comment: @John Just to be clear: None of the proposed actions work for me because none of them solves the OP question. They're manual workarounds. They do not tell me how could I prevent Windows from shutting down when a specific task is running. However, this is getting more and more off-topic. Thank you for your suggestions, I would keep them in mind if no solution is suggested.

Comment: There's probably no good solution to your request simply because allowing a process to continue to execute in the face of a shutdown command is a contradiction. The shutdown command means terminate everything in an orderly manner. When AC/mains power is lost and the UPS alarm is going off, you need an immediate shutdown. But you have a special case, and want to keep the system up; your request is selfish. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Can you use a sleep command instead of shutdown? A process can defer the sleep action.

Comment: @sawdust My request is selfish? To whom? Is it really that hard to keep things on topic or simply tell me respectfully that it is not possible? I simply want to achieve with my task what many Windows apps already achieve, which is putting the shutdown on hold until the task is finished or until I manually ask for it to finish anyway.

Comment: Perhaps "selfish" is not quite the right word. I would probably characterize it as an "unreasonable demand" (based on a skit from Space Ghost: Coast to Coast, that I am partial to). It is possible to let an app block a shutdown by calling the windows API,  but that means that you must have access to the application code and environment in which to compile it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate

Comment: @Frank Thomas After some digging and tweaking, I got it working by using the API you suggested (plus several others), so now Windows is finally able to satisfy my selfish needs! Thanks a lot for your help.